# Qual è il sostantivo per "Impersonare"?

Tags: verbs, nouns

Qual è il sostantivo che descrive l'azione dell'impersonare: "impersonazione" o "impersonamento"?
Cercando i termini online ho trovato utilizzi per tutt'e due: per citare un esempio, esistono due libri dai titoli "Persona e *impersonazione*: Uso rituale delle maschere presso gli Zuni" e "Classificatori e *impersonamento* nella lingua dei segni italiana".
Consultando vocabolari online della lingua italiana non ho, invece, trovato definizioni per nessuna delle due parole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impersonamento%2C%20impersonazione&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3) sembra indicare che i due termini sono usati all'incirca con la stessa frequenza, anche se apparentemente negli ultimi anni l'uso di *impersonazione* pare più comune. Google Search ([1](https://www.google.it/search?q=impersonazione), [2](https://www.google.it/search?q=impersonamento)) conferma questo *trend*, fornendo 900 risultati per *impersonamento* contro i 3.800  di *impersonazione*.

Ciò non significa che *impersonamento* abbia una connotazione antiquata, o che non suoni altrettanto "naturale"; tra le due parole non c'è nessuna sfumatura di significato, e un interlocutore comprenderà entrambi i termini.

Comment: Così non ce n'è uno più corretto dell'altro ma sono entrambi validi... Grazie per la risposta.

Answer (score 2):

Penso si debba dire che sono, oramai, entrambe scorrette, perché completamente in disuso. La risposta alla domanda "qual'è il sostantivo per impersonare?", in vari casi è "imitazione". Se invece si tratta di una situazione che non permette l'uso di questo termine, si usa l'infinito o l'infinito passato:

> He was arrested for *impersonating* a police officer
>   È stato arrestato per l'imitazione di un agente di polizia (*)
>   È stato arrestato per aver impersonato un agente di polizia

Identicamente, volendo riscrivere oggigiorno le frasi che suggerivi penso andrebbero cambiate (a meno di volersi atteggiare ad esperti del campo che coniano o riesumano il linguaggio di settore)

> "La persona e l'impersonare: Uso rituale delle maschere presso gli Zuni"
>   "I classificatori e l'impersonare nella lingua dei segni italiana"

Comment: Su quale pianeta *imitazione* è sinonimo di *impersonazione*? Nel tuo esempio sull'agente di polizia le due traduzioni hanno significati completamente diversi. Nella prima la persona arrestata (*che potrebbe anche essere un poliziotto*) stava facendo le stesse azioni che faceva l'agente ("tipo specchio") e l'arresto sarebbe alquanto strano; nel secondo caso invece stava cercando di truffare qualcuno facendosi passare per un agente di polizia quando non lo era. Almeno, questo è il significato che se ne trae. Forse conviene cercare un esempio migliore se vuoi supportare quella tesi.

Comment: Forse dovresti leggere meglio prima di commentare. Prima di fare l'esempio del poliziotto ho scritto proprio: "Se invece si tratta di una situazione che non permette l'uso di questo termine, si usa l'infinito o l'infinito passato".  L'esempio in questione è proprio un caso in cui non si può usare certo "imitazione". Però "ha impersonato Renzo Arbore" e "ha imitato Renzo Arbore" hanno lo stesso identico significato.

Comment: Quindi secondo te mettere un esempio che contraddice quello che hai appena detto dovrebbe rendere la tua risposta migliore? Per come è scritto sembra che tu voglia fornire un argomento a supporto, quando invece non lo è. Se non espliciti questo il senso che ne risulta è sbagliato. Di norma la costruzione *asserzione: esempio* implica che *esempio* mostri quello che si intendeva in *asserzione*, non l'opposto o qualcosa di diverso.

Comment: Non c'è sostantivo per una traduzione diretta, si può usare imitazione o l'infinito. L'esempio si riferisce al secondo caso, l'esempio di Renzo Arbore al primo. Non è difficile. Dici che ti pare confuso, ma ho scritto "SE INVECE si tratta di una situazione che NON PERMETTE L'USO DI QUESTO TERMINE", come fa a risultarti confuso? Ora, puoi accettare graciously di aver male interpretato l'esempio e la seconda parte del discorso, credendo si riferisse a "imitazione", o puoi continuare a trollarmi. Un consiglio per la prossima volta: "se mi sono confuso io, può capitare a altri" è onesto e funziona

Answer (score 2):

> Cercando i termini online ho trovato utilizzi per tutt'e due: per
>   citare un esempio, esistono due libri dai titoli "Persona e
>   impersonazione: Uso rituale delle maschere presso gli Zuni" e
>   "Classificatori e impersonamento nella **lingua dei segni** italiana".

Il termine *impersonamento* è un termine tecnico della LIS e probabilmente ha la medesima origine anglosassone

Il termine *impersonazione* è stato pian piano mutuato dall'inglese prima nella psicoanalisi, nel gergo teatrale *("la sua impersonazione di Amleto")* e pian piano si farà strada come tanti neologismi